# npm linked local library requires node_modules while git linked libarary (same) doesn't

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, npm-link

Sorry for the bad title (really don't know what other titles I can give to this question).

Long story short, as a first-time react-component library developer. I am using **webpack 4** to transpile my **fancy-react-component-lib** to a module.

Everything goes well until I start using [npm-link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) to accelerate my local dev speed.

So the major issue is although I have specified as following

```
//webpack.fancy-react-component-lib.config.js
...    
externals: {
        react: {
          root: 'React',
          commonjs2: 'react',
          commonjs: 'react',
          amd: 'react',
          umd: 'react',
        },
        'react-dom': {
          root: 'ReactDOM',
          commonjs2: 'react-dom',
          commonjs: 'react-dom',
          amd: 'react-dom',
          umd: 'react-dom',
        },
      }
...

//package.json
...
"dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
   ...
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    ...
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0"
  }
...
```

So if I have imported the module via git syntax

```
"fancy-react-component-lib" :"git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/fancy-react-component-lib.git#test1.0.11"
```

Everything works fine, there would be only one copy of **react** in the final bundled js.

But if I bunded with the npm-link to the project folder, the second copy of react get added the final bunded js.

Could anyone tell me why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since no one is providing a better answer I will just post here how I have solved the issue.

First of all npm link is nothing more than just a symbolic link. Instead of using the npm link like suggested by react's solution page. I have tried to [create symbolic links](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/creating-soft-link-or-symbolic-link/) myself and it works.

```
ln -s [your_fancy_lib_project] [project/node_moduels/your_fancey_lib_project]
```

Also you need to create the links in **[your_fancy_lib]/node_modules/react** and 
**[your_fancy_lib]/node_moduels/react-dom** to
**[project]/node_moduels/react** and **[project]/node_moduels/react-dom**

```
ln -s [project/node_moduels/react] [your_fancey_lib_project/node_moduels/react]
ln -s [project/node_moduels/react-dom] [your_fancey_lib_project/node_moduels/react-dom]
```

Of course remember to clean the folder before you create the symbolic link.